# Dynamic Web Scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape data from amazon using selenium and beautiful soup..
I have scraped and obtained data from the first page and have a defined a function for it and managed to get the second page opened with the Click() method...
The soup objects that were used in first page is similar to the objects in second page...I am planning to scrape data till page 6....
Was wondering if i could apply the function defined for the first page to the next 5 pages and append the data, which can later be exported as csv.
Any suggestions regarding this would be appreciated..

```py
def data_collection():
    title = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-size-base-plus a-color- 
    base a-text-normal")

    all_specs = [specs.getText() for specs in title]
    brands = [items.split(' ', 1)[0] for items in all_specs]  #Brand

    phones = [text.split(')')[0].split('(') for text in all_specs]  
    spec = []
    for i in phones:
        for j in i:
            spec.append(j)
    model = spec[::2]             #Model

    specifications = spec[1::2]   #Specs

    s_price_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-price-whole")
    selling_price = [price.getText() for price in s_price_obj]   #Price

    review_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-icon-alt")
    review = [ratings.getText() for ratings in review_obj]  
    review = review[:24]          #Ratings

    quantity_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-size-base")
    quantity_sold = [items.getText() for items in quantity_obj]
    quantity_sold = quantity_sold[:24]   #Quantity Sold

    page_number = ['1']*24  #Page Number

    Date = date.today()
    Date = [str(Date)]*24   #Date

    data = [brands, model, specifications, selling_price, review, 
    quantity_sold, page_number, Date]

    return data
```

The above is the function defined...Open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:-

Re-define your data_collection method to accept page source parsed by BeautifulSoup

```
def data_collection(soup):
    title = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-size-base-plus a-color- base a-text-normal")

    all_specs = [specs.getText() for specs in title]
    brands = [items.split(' ', 1)[0] for items in all_specs]  #Brand

    phones = [text.split(')')[0].split('(') for text in all_specs]  
    spec = []
    for i in phones:
        for j in i:
            spec.append(j)
    model = spec[::2]             #Model

    specifications = spec[1::2]   #Specs

    s_price_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-price-whole")
    selling_price = [price.getText() for price in s_price_obj]   #Price

    review_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-icon-alt")
    review = [ratings.getText() for ratings in review_obj]  
    review = review[:24]          #Ratings

    quantity_obj = soup.find_all(name = "span", class_ = "a-size-base")
    quantity_sold = [items.getText() for items in quantity_obj]
    quantity_sold = quantity_sold[:24]   #Quantity Sold

    page_number = ['1']*24  #Page Number

    Date = date.today()
    Date = [str(Date)]*24   #Date

    data = [brands, model, specifications, selling_price, review, 
    quantity_sold, page_number, Date]

    return data
```

Then loop through each page, get the page source, parse it using BeautifulSoup and pass it to the data_collection function. Example:-

```
#from page(1..6)
for i in range(1,7):
    #change page=i in the url to iterate through the pages
    url=f'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=mobile+phones&page={i}&qid=1632394501&ref=sr_pg_2'
    driver.get(url)

    #get current page source
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')

    #call data_collection function
    data=data_collection(soup)

    #code to append data to csv
```